# Rate limiting in AWS Lambdas

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway, aws-serverless

Say I have few lambdas connected with DynamoDb, and the number of invocations needs to be limited to a hard limit if 500 requests say, after this the lambda shouldn't get invoked and cost us billing, how can this be done, I tried out API gateway quota in this we need to have the limit on each of the API and api keys.

Need some other way to implement this.

I tried throttling, but that doesn't completely stop the lambdas from being getting invoked, so this doesn't solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this can be achieved using AWS limits. You will need to build it - maybe store the counter and check against. However, what are yoy trying to achieve with this architecture? It doesn't sound right to stop the applications from working after n number of invocations.

Comment: Yes this approach has come to my mind, just thinking out loud 
1. To store the request quota (limit) in Dynamodb
2. Whenever this limit value falls below 50
3. We can have a Cloudwatch alarm being triggered
4. This alarm can call a new Lambda which can reset the permissions of the main lambdas
5. This can prevent the main lambdas from getting invoked now onwards

Let me know if this can work or do we need some other approach. @skzi

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure on your use-case, so I'm not sure on which solution to recommend. Knowing the reason you'd wanna limit to 500 would help.

You can use a Cloudwatch alarm that alarms at 500 invocations, have the alarm trigger a Lambda function and that function calls `UpdateEventSourceMapping` and disables the connection between the stream and Lambda. This would prevent the Lambda from being invoked again until you enable it.

Comment: But as the event source is AWS API Gateway this approach, will not work.
I had in mind if we can make the `reserved concurrency to 0`, will the lambda serve the new coming requests from AWS API Gateway?
Or does it rejects them and takes them later when we make the reserve concurrency back greater than 0?